# What's the relationship of $e_G$ to $G \times G$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

**Context**: 1st year Mathematics BSc.

Let
\begin{align}
& G = \langle g \rangle \text{ be a cyclic group of order } n, \tag{0.1}\\
& e_1 \text{ be the neutral element of } G, \tag{0.2}\\
& e_2 \text{ be the neutral element of } G \times G. \tag{0.3}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
e_2=(g^i,g^j) \text{, for some } 1\leq i,j, \leq n, \tag{1}
\end{align}
so, for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align}
e_2
&=e_2^k \tag{2.1}\\
&=(g^i,g^j)^k \tag{2.2} \\
&=\left((g^i)^k,(g^j)^k\right) \tag{2.3} \\
&=\left(g^{ik},g^{jk}\right), \tag{2.4}
\end{align}
so, for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align}
& g^i=g^{ik}, \tag{3.1}\\
& g^j=g^{jk}, \tag{3.2}
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
& g=g^k. \tag{4}\\
\end{align}

This kind of looks like it might mean that
$$g^i=g^j=e_1, \tag{5}$$

but I don't know if that's right or how to prove it.

Comment: You know that a group has only one identity element. Given $\langle g,h\rangle\in G\times G$, what is the product $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle\langle g,h\rangle$ in $G$?

Comment: If $e$ is the neutral element of a group $G$, the neutral element of $G\times G$ is $(e,e)$. Is there a purpose behind this more complicated approach?

Comment: @Thorgott This is what I suspected and am trying to derive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship is that $e_2=(e_1,e_1)$.  You can check it by doing the multiplication with any other element of the product.

This is true more generally, not just for cyclic $G$.

Answer (score 1):

The neutral element of $G \times G$, call it $e_2$ is exactly $(e_1,e_1)$ where $e_1$ is the identity of $G$. So your conclusion that $g^i = g^j = e_1$ is correct based on the assumption that $e_2 = (g^i,g^j)$. To prove that $e_2 = (e_1,e_1)$ all you have to do is go through the definition of what the identity element of a group must satisfy. Does $(g^k,g^l)(e_1,e_1) = (e_1,e_1)(g^k,g^l) = (g^k,g^l)$ for any choice of $g^k,g^l$? The fact that $G$ is cyclic is not relevant for this reasoning to hold.